# How would i go about using 2 arrays in an && if statement

Tags: c, if-statement

The first part of my program i creating 2 different arrays, the login id and password. After that has all been entered I would like the program to have 5 different IF statements that checks the 2 arrays to see if the ID and Password combinations are correct.

I am currently trying it like this for the first one with no success

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char id[5];
char password[8];
int i, j, k;
int access;
char c;

printf("Please enter your ID: ");
scanf("%5c", id);
printf("\nPlease enter your password: ");
for(k = 0; k < 8; k++)
{
    do
    {

        c = getch();
        if(c != '\n' || c != '\r')
        {
            password[k] = c;    
            putchar('*');
            break;
        }

    }while(c != '\n' || c != '\r');

}

for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    if(password[i] >= '0' && password[i] <= '9')
    {
        password[i] = (char)((password[i] - '0' + 4 )% 10 + '0');
    }

    if((password[i] >= 'a' && password[i] <= 'z') || (password[i] >= 'A' &&             password[i] <= 'Z') )
    {
        password[i] = (char)((password[i] - 'a' + 4) % 26 + 'a');
    }
}
if((strcmp(password, "abcdefgh") == 0) && (strcmp(id,"ft234")==0))
{
    access = 1;
    printf("Logged in.\n\n");

}    
else if((strcmp(password, "bcdefghi")==0) && (strcmp(id, "ty394")==0))
{
    access = 1;
    printf("Logged in.\n\n");

}
}
```

Comment: Take a look, how to use `strcmp` correctly. You will need to compare the result of `strcmp`, like `if (strcmp(password, "242jfjsd") == 0) {...}`. Though, your question is not really clear to me.

Comment: Lolz, if this code was to get incorporated in some live website. The horror and excitement. :0

Comment: What learning resource are you using?

Comment: Please have a very close look at a good C book. No offence, but you are apparently lacking the very basics.

Comment: Learning from google, and I want the array, I want the program to check both arrays with multiple if statements, and which ever one they meet, enter into the if statement. My question is how do I have 2 different arrays in the same action using &&.

Comment: Yes thank you all for clarifying that I am doing it wrong.

Comment: i use `scanf("%5c", id);` for  the id, and for the password i use a loop that has getch() to mask the input

Comment: I have done that right before the if statement, both values come out correctly, but are just not being used by the if statement, I have updated my post with the current if statement I am using now

Comment: Does not seem to work when executed separately

Comment: Ill try to make remake my program in a smaller format and edit my post.

Comment: Code in my main post now recreates the issue.

Comment: That is what i had originally, was testing using 5 and 8, sorry should have changed that back. Still having the same problem unfortunately

Comment: Thank you very much, after changing both of those the program is now working! Thank you!

Comment: Your loop will never stop - one of the conditions is always true

Comment: You should not change the program in question, since this makes your question post nonsensical. When you figured a solution out, you might post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**First problem**

In C language you declare strings (arrays of characters) with double-quotes, not simple quotes.

Ex: `char string[20] = "my string"`

Using simple-quotes declares a **single** character.

Ex: `char ch = 'a'`

**Second problem**

You can't compare strings natively in low-level languages such as C language. You must use `strcmp`.

**Solution**

```
if ((strcmp(password, "string_passwd") == 0) && (strcmp(login, "string_login") == 0)) {
  <both password and login are ok>
} else {
  <one (or both) of password or/and login are not ok>
}
```

Comment: In my program I am using double quotes, sorry for the miss type when trying to make easier to read. I have modified my set of 5 if statements to have the same structure as the example you provided, but my program is still skipping over it regardless of what has been put. Would it be safe to assume the problem is being caused somewhere else in the program?